# FQL Fauna Function - Query Indexed Document Data Given Conditions

Tags: database, faunadb

I have a collection of shifts for employees, data (trimmed out some details, but this is the structure for start/end times) looks like this:

```
{
  "ref": Ref(Collection("shifts"), "123451234512345123"),
  "ts": 1234567891012345,
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "start": {
      "time": 1659279600000
    },
    "end": {
      "time": 1659283200000
    },
    "location": "12341234-abcd-1234-cdef-123412341234"
  }
}
```

I have an index that will query return an array of shifts_by_location in this format: `["id", "startTime", "endTime"]` ...

Now I want to create a user-defined-function to filter these results "start" and "end" times to fall in between given dayStart and dayEnd times to get shifts by date, hoping to get some FQL assistance here, thanks!

Here's my broken attempt:

```
Query(
  Lambda(
    ["location_id", "dayStart", "dayEnd"], // example: ["124-abd-134", 165996000, 165922000]
    Map(
      Paginate(Match(Index("shifts_by_location"), Var("location_id"))),
      Lambda(["id", "startTime", "endTime"],
        If(
          And(
            GTE(Var("startTime"), Var("dayStart")), // GOAL -> shift starts after 8am on given day
            LTE(Var("endTime"), Var("dayEnd")) // GOAL -> shift ends before 5pm on given day
          ),
          Get(Var("shift")) // GOAL -> return shift for given day
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: What is broken about your attempt?

Comment: I believe this was actually an invalid query but I wanted to get the idea across of what I wanted to accomplish, but I have found a working solution that I am using at the moment

Comment: The only thing I see wrong with the original query is the missing `else` condition in the `If` call. You only have `If(And(...), Get(...)`, not `If(And(...), Get(...), null)` (or similar).

Comment: Understood, thanks @eskwayrd, actually I was able to accomplish the If-then-Get with Filter

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution with this query, the biggest fix was really just to use a filter over the map, which seems obvious in hindsight:

```
Query(
  Lambda(
    ["location_id", "dayStart", "dayEnd"],
    Filter(
      Paginate(Match(Index("shifts_by_location"), Var("location_id"))),
      Lambda(
        ["start", "end", "id"],
        And(GTE(Var("start"), Var("dayStart")), LTE(Var("end"), Var("dayEnd")))
      )
    )
  )
)
```